# WCF Callback Client Failing

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, callback

I have created a WCF service which has a callback. I have created a sample client which will subscribe to these callbacks. I have been using the ListBasedPublishSubscribe sample as a base for this. However when I try and setup the unique callback address in the client with this code

```
        context = new InstanceContext(null, new MyClass());
        client = new MyClient(context);
        WSDualHttpBinding binding = (WSDualHttpBinding)client.Endpoint.Binding;
        string clientcallbackaddress = binding.ClientBaseAddress.AbsoluteUri;
        clientcallbackaddress += Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        binding.ClientBaseAddress = new Uri(clientcallbackaddress);
```

The third line fails because client.Endpoint.Binding.ClientBaseAddress is null. Should this not be null (I assume so for the sample to work) and why is this the case in my app? Have I forgotten to do something?

Comment: Is there anything for this in web.config / app.config?

Comment: Have you got `clientBaseAddress` defined in `wsDualHttpBinding` in the config file?

Comment: Was there ever a solution to this?  I am having the same problem.